# org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings_Decorated cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectInternal

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I tried to create spring boot application:

I selected components I need from `https://start.spring.io/`

Now I want to build the application and it fall downs:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where: 
Settings file 'D:\objectsharingsystem\settings.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'object-sharing-system'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.gradle.java']
   > org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings_Decorated cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectInternal

* Try:   
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

**settings.gradle:**

```
rootProject.name = 'object-sharing-system'
apply plugin: 'java'
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Please help to find mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`settings.gradle` can not handle application of `Project` level plugin.

Remove `apply plugin` and `compileJava` from `settings.gradle`.
You already have your `sourceCompatibility` set in build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:settings_file) where it says

> method calls within the settings file is delegated to a settings object. Look at the Settings class in the API documentation for more information.

Unlike `build.gradle`, the `apply` method in `settings.gradle` expects a `Plugin<Settings>` and not a `Plugin<Project>`. The `java` plugin is a `Plugin<Project>` and can't be applied like this in `settings.gradle`

Comment: .1. How to fix? 2. I just download project from https://start.spring.io/. In which step I did error?

Comment: Your `settings.gradle` is garbage. You can't apply `java` plugin here

Comment: Just remove it ?